# how can i change the format of the date by using Format Function , DAX , Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a column "Sta" type date/time, and I want to change the format of it to be like this format "YYYYMM", or "MM-YYYY" into a new column.

and this error appears to me each time I want to change the format of the column into the new one !!!!

### [image] [image]

***any idea how can I change the format by using the Format Function?***

Comment: Which model are you using - DirectQuery or Import?

Comment: DirectQuery model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format function you use expect just one row. With a `Max()` function before it will work.

[image]

However, what you are looking for is in the relationship tab:

[image]

Click on your date column then go to `Properties > Date time Format > Custom Format`:

[image]

Here you can type in your custom format.

Answer (score 1):

It's explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax#remarks) that `FORMAT` function **is not supported** for use in DirectQuery mode. Also take a look at [DAX formula compatibility in DirectQuery mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/dax-formula-compatibility-in-directquery-mode-ssas-2016?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) article.